# Querying content provider for url returns no results

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a pretty basic content provider that stores 4 columns in a sqlite db.  These columns are an auto incrementing key, a url as text, a long, and a blob for an image.  When i try and query off the url, i get no results, even though i know the row exists in the database.  What do I need to do with/to the url in order for the selection to pull it.

```
//called when storing
private void addKey(String url, final Bitmap bm) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ImagesContentProvider.URL, "'" + url + "'");
    values.put(ImagesContentProvider.TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /* ignored for PNG */, bos);
    values.put(ImagesContentProvider.BITMAP, bos.toByteArray());
cr.insert(ImagesContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values); //cr is content resolver
}


//called for querying
private void query(String url) {
    String selection =  ImagesContentProvider.URL + "='" + url+ "'";
    Cursor resultsCursor = cr.query(ImagesContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                null, selection, null, null);
    if (!resultsCursor.moveToFirst()) { 
            Log.d(TAG, "Not found in DB");
            resultsCursor.close();

    } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "found in DB");          
            resultsCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: because youre searching for url like `http://someurl` and in database you have `'http://someurl'`(with `'`) ... if you guess why - good for you if not ... programming is not for you ......

Comment: Wow.  A little harsh.  Regardless, it turns out that I just had a copy and paste error.  As you said I was adding "'url'" and searching for "url".  Thanks for catching my mistake.

Comment: "A little harsh" .. maybe, but you did provide both inserting and quering in question... i was sure that you will find this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know that you already know the answer but ...
error was here

```
values.put(ImagesContentProvider.URL, "'" + url + "'");
```

this should be:

```
values.put(ImagesContentProvider.URL, url); 
//or you should add ' when you do query
```

you unecessary escape string in ContentValues ...

to prevent such errors do not escape string by yorself ... use parametrized queries

```
Cursor resultsCursor = cr.query(ImagesContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
         null, ImagesContentProvider.URL + "=?", new String[] { url }, null);
```